# Any champ builder app or addon for League of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends, mods

I'm looking for an app (for android or PC) for make my own build for differents champs. I don't know if it exists, but if it exist, where i can get it?

Comment: HI David, and welcome to Arqade!  Unfortunately, shopping recommendations are off-topic, as per the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).  Also, take a look at the [about page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) to get a better feel for the site.

Comment: You are wrong, it isn't a shopping recommendation, i'm looking to an addon or anything that helps League of legends to be better. It can be an app or a desktop program

Comment: Just because it's free doesn't mean it's not a shopping recommendation.  In general, Arqade isn't very suited for recommendation-type questions.  We've tried them, and found they don't work very well.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I did not expect to be treated like shopping recommendations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://lol.fanrealm.net/OJeq0b4QJaObsPEQCPQm/#stats

I think this is what you are looking for. It is a very well designed and complete champion builder. Where you can also import your own runepages (from your actual lol account) for more convenience. Take some time to get used to the UI cause it can be a bit chaotic in the first 5 minutes.

Plus in public beta server there is already something similar implemented. In case you are only interested in remembering full item builds.
Info here: http://www.surrenderat20.net/2013/04/41-pbe-update.html